Bayesian: Formally comparing prior and posterior distributions
Consider Bayesian inference in the regression model:
$$ \begin{align*} y &= \beta_0+\beta_1x_1+\beta_2x_2 + \varepsilon \\ \varepsilon &\sim 
\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2) \end{align*}$$
Suppose we are interested in how informative the data is about each coefficient - that is, we are interested in investigating the how different the prior, $p(\beta_i)$, and the posterior $p(\beta_i|Y)$ are from each other, for each coefficient.
One thought I had was to compare independent draws from the prior and the posterior distributions, as suggested in a different context here. I'm not sure how valid this is in the present context, since the prior and posterior are not independent of each other.
Another thought I had would be to run special versions of MCMC, where one coefficient was drawn from its prior instead of its posterior. For example, when focusing on $\beta_0$, we would successively draw from: $p(\beta_0)$, $p(\beta_1,\beta_2|Y,\beta_0,\sigma^2)$, and $p(\sigma^2|Y,\beta_0,\beta_1,\beta_2)$. Then we could compare the marginal likelihood of this model to the marginal likelihood of the full model. However, this would be fairly cumbersome as the MCMC procedure would have to be rewritten slightly for each special case, and would involve approximating the marginal likelihood, which I want to avoid if possible.
Is either of these approaches appropriate? Are there any widely accepted ways of comparing prior and posterior distributions for each individual parameter?

The ratio of posterior to prior $p(β|Y)/p(β)$ as a function  of $β$ seems like a fairly natural way to quantify 'how different the prior and the posterior are'. When interest is on a specific parameter, whether you seek to look at that ratio for the margin of interest, or consider the profile likelihood would be a matter to consider

Relevant paper https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-35/issue-2/Checking-for-Prior-Data-Conflict-Using-Prior-to-Posterior-Divergences/10.1214/19-STS731.full

Similar Q (without answer) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/526180/distance-measures-between-prior-and-posterior

Thanks for the citation and ideas.
For @Glen_b's suggestion, wouldn't this ratio be proportional to the likelihood, since $p(\beta|Y) = \frac{p(Y|\beta)p(\beta)}{p(Y)}$? So instead of comparing prior and posterior, we would be comparing prior and likelihood (which is the piece of the posterior independent of the prior). In my case, the unconditional posterior is not a known distribution (I only have draws from MCMC). I suppose I could fit a Normal or Kernel density to the posterior, then approximate the "profile likelihood" as $p(\beta_i|Y) / p(\beta_i)$ for all values of $\beta_i$.

Then, once I have $p(Y|\beta_i) \propto \frac{p(\beta_i|Y)}{p(\beta_i)}$, I could compare $p(Y|\beta_i)$ to $p(\beta_i)$ using, for example, the 'arbitrary pairings' approach mentioned in the first answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/548295/bayesian-comparing-means-of-two-posterior-samples-help-a-frequentist-out

Yes, indeed, it's the likelihood, the likelihood is exactly how the prior is modified by the data to produce the posterior (as a function of the parameter). So (as I mentioned above) the question then for you to ponder is whether you seek marginal likelihood, profile likelihood or something else.
